# Why is the TextChanged event not firing when using up/down arrow keys to change ComboBox value in VB.Net Windows Forms?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am working on a VB.Net Windows Forms application. I added a ComboBox to my form, set its "DropDownStyle" property to DropDownList and added a few items in it. Now, when I am running the application and changing the combo box value with the mouse, everything is working fine and TextChanged event is firing. But if I am changing its values using up/down arrow keys, the TextChanged event is not firing.

Can anybody explain why?

Regards,
Shishir Wahi

If I change the "DropDownStyle" property to DropDown then the issue is gone, but I have to use DropDownList style only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user can't enter text if `DropDownStyle` is set to `DropDownList` so the `TextChanged` event should be irrelevant. It will only be raised if the `Text` property gets set, which is clearly not happening in the case. It will be raised when `DropDownStyle` is set to `DropDown` because the control basically contains a text box, so the event works just as it would for a `TextBox` control.

You should be handling `SelectIndexChanged`, `SelectedValueChanged` or `SelectionChangeCommitted`, depending on the specific circumstances. The `TextUpdate` event might also give you what you want but is probably not as appropriate as the others.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I got your point, but the problem is that the combobox's Text property is bound to a field of my database table and if the textchanged event is not raised, the underlying dataset will not get updated.
And why is this working fine when I am doing it with mouse?

Comment: @ShishirWahi, depending on the circumstances, you should probably be binding to the SelectedItem or SelectedValue instead.

Comment: binding to the SelectedItem solved the issue. Thanks!